# Django cannot import settings

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use django-admin dbshell (any other cmd gives the same result) on my project. And I got

```
 You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

So I did

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

and now I get

```
no module named 'mysite'
```

Of course I replace 'mysite' with the name of my app.
Btw I already had this in my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

any idea?
Thanks

Comment: How many settings files do you have? E.g. `local.py`, `prod.py`, etc.

Comment: Which Django version you are using?

Comment: Django version 1.10.5, I only have a single settings.py file in the root of my app.
Btw if I put "mysite.settings" in DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE then I won't even be able to run `django-admin` on it's own and get the help message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do:

```
python manage.py dbshell --settings=mysite.settings
```

Comment: Note that `./manage.py` command will default to `mysite.settings` - you only need `--settings` to specify a custom settings file.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, you should only use `django-admin` to start a new project. Once the project has been created, use `./manage.py` instead. The `manage.py` script takes care of loading the settings for you.

When you use `django-admin`, the directory containing `mysite` needs to be on the Python path for Django to be able to load `mysite.settings`.